# Need to create an ArrayList of type FlashCard which stores values as a String?

Tags: java, arraylist

For my assignment, I have been asked to create an ArrayList of FlashCards which store a series of questions and answers. Naturally, these would be stored in a String type but the ArrayList in which they are stored in must be of type FlashCard so I'm confused as to how this would happen. Here is what I have so far:

```
 public class FlashCard 
{

         ArrayList<FlashCard> cardlist = new ArrayList<FlashCard>();


FlashCard(String question, String answer)
{

}


public void getQuestion() 
{

cardlist.add("1Q - By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?");
cardlist.add("2Q - Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?");
cardlist.add("3Q - Which state was Franklin Roosevelt born in?");
cardlist.add("4Q - In which year did Roosevelt become Governor of New York?");
cardlist.add("5Q - What was the name of Franklin Roosevelt's wife?");
cardlist.add("6Q - How many children did Franklin Roosevelt have?");
cardlist.add("7Q - From which university did Franklin Roosevelt graduate with an A.B in history?");
cardlist.add("8Q - What was the first name of Franklin Roosevelt's 5th cousin, who was also President?");
cardlist.add("9Q - Which disease is believed to be the causes of Franklin Roosevelt's paralysis?");
cardlist.add("10Q - At what age did Franklin Roosevelt die?");

}

public void getAnswer()
{

 cardlist.add("1A - FDR");
 cardlist.add("2A - 32");
 cardlist.add("3A - New York");
 cardlist.add("4A - 1929");
 cardlist.add("5A - Elenor");
 cardlist.add("6A - 6");
 cardlist.add("7A - Hrrvard");
 cardlist.add("8A - Theodore");
 cardlist.add("9A - Polio");
 cardlist.add("10A - 63");

}

}
```

Any ideas on how I would store these into a FlashCard ArrayList? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why would your `FlashCard` class contain a list of `FlashCards`?

Comment: My assignment will then create a `Quiz` class which involves these FlashCards. Would this still work if they were to be of type `String`?

Comment: Each FlashCard contains a list of FlashCards, those FlashCards also each containing a list of FlashCards, etc. Do you see the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

To add a Flashcard to the list you have to put in the Object Flashcard, not String values.

Example:

```
cardlist.add(new Flashcard("1Q - By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?", "1A - FDR"));
cardlist.add(new Flashcard("2Q - Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?", "2A - 32"));
```

Comment: Ah I see, I must create an object for each one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would also move your cardlist to a separate class than FalshCard.  Then you can have an object with the properties answer and question in that object and use getters/setters to manipulate a single variable at a time.